# JQuery Plugin Optomisations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/no1_melman/fz52E/) that I have created today. It's a jquery plugin for a star rating.

It renders everything it needs inside a div tag, and uses settings to customise.

```
$('#myNewRatingControl').makeStar({ 
    sourceImage: urlOfImage 
}).starRating({
    sourceImage: urlOfImage,
    hoverImage: urlOfImage,
    initialRating: 3
});
```

This works a treat, and I'm really impressed with it. However, there a couple of things I would like to do to optomise it. I've tried to implement these optimisations but have had no luck.

They are as follows:

1. Condense them into one function, I couldn't do this because of the click event handlers attached to the images. They are only applied when the DOM has been updated, and it isn't till the jquery function returns it's output. At least that is what I've understood please use my JQuery to show me otherwise! -SOLVED SEE FIDDLE AT TOP.
2. Image preloading. I have come across some image preloaders, but I have no idea how to use them in this context. Where to put them into, and how to call them once they've been preloaded.
3. Since the first one has been solved, I was wondering how to make the second function private inside the plugin(scope)?

Please could you use my fiddle to show me how to achieve these optomisations?

Thanks,

Comment: In `makeStar`, instead of `return $(this).append(/*..*/);`, why not `return $(this).append(/*..*/).starRating(settings);`?

Comment: Why don't you use existing plugin : http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/?

Comment: ooo, that sounds good, do I have to change starRating to make it private, can i change it so it is?

Comment: my fiddle has been update with this improvement!!!

Comment: By private, you mean that you want to sell it? Check the licence tab for more information

Comment: @sdespont I was quite happy implementing my own rating, this has taught me so much, in future I can make other plugins now, also it will teach me about image preloading, all useful stuff if I'm going to develop plugins!

Comment: @sdespont no, make the function private, as in access level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have this new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz52E/11/) which I have done the following to:

1. Shortened the code
2. Refactored the code
3. Enabled Tri State Stars (hover, selected, unselected)
4. Introduced another setting for selectedImage

The only thing left now is:

1. Privatise function scope
2. Do image preloading

Take a look at both pieces of code to understand the different optomisations done.

Tri State Code:

```
    function setImageSrcProper()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < settings.numberOfStars; i++)
        {
            var id = '#star' + i;
            var selected = $(id).attr('data-selected');
            var hover = $(id).attr('data-hover');
            if (selected == 'true')
            {
                $(id).attr('src', settings.selectedImage);   
            }
            else
            {
                $(id).attr('src', settings.sourceImage);   
            }

            if (hover=='true')
            {
                $(id).attr('src', settings.hoverImage);   
            }
        }
    }
```

I use the `data-selected` and `data-hover` for the tri state, the basic idea is that at all times the stars are either going to be selected or unselected. Then when the mouse is introduced, hover will override any of these states. On mouse out, the states will return back to what they were, and all `data-hover` will be falsified.